# CSS how to prevent element overlap and keep element fixed while resizing the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, element

I am new to `CSS` and I have few elements below shown. When I zoom in/out the page, I found that the element overlap with each other. Basically, I have 2 `div` for storing the Button/ Input Field and 2 `div` for holding the table. How can I prevent element overlap and keep element fixed while resizing the page/ in different resolution by `CSS`?

DOM:

```
<div id='itemBar1' style={{verticalAlign: 'baseline',  position:'static', zIndex:"999", height:"5%"}} >
  <div style={{padding:"5px 5px 5px 10px", float: "left"}} >
    <Button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="table1" style={{verticalAlign: 'baseline', height:"50%", position:'static'}}>
  <Table Component>
</div>

<div id='itemBar2' style={{verticalAlign: 'baseline', position:'static',  height:"5%"}}>
</div>

<div id="table2" style={{verticalAlign: 'baseline', height:"40%", position:'static'}}>
  <Table Component>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into Z-index?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess I guess Z-index can't help. The layout of the html is vertical and when I zoom in, the upper element and lower element will gradually overlap.

Comment: did you try using "background-position: fixed"